# Proving a set statement

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

$A, B, C$ are subsets of a set $U$:

$A ⊆ B → A ∩ B$ $\nsubseteq$ $C$    $(1)$

$A ⊆ B ∨ A ⊆ C$     $(2)$

$A ∩ C ⊆ B$   $(3)$

I have to prove that this is valid:

$A ∩ B$ $\nsubseteq$ $C$   $(4)$

It is recommended to use this in our proof:

$X ⊆ Y ↔ X ∩ Y = X$ $(5)$

Should this be solved by mathematical induction or somehow else? I don't know what to do about that. Sorry for bad English. That is not my first language.

Comment: It would be much better if you showed how much work you have done, and where exactly are you stuck. Which statements are premises, what do you want proven... so forth.

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve it by cases on (2).
If $A \subseteq B$, you're done by (1).

Suppose now that  $A \subseteq C$ (6).

By (6) we can say $A \cap C = A$.

So by (3): $A \cap C = A \subseteq B$.

So $A \subseteq B$ holds.

By (1): $A \cap B \nsubseteq C$.